make two programs in one make command
I want to make my main and test programs with makefile.
I tried to run this make command but it compiles just the library_management:
# Compiler and flags
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Iinclude

# Directories
SRC_DIR = src
INCLUDE_DIR = include
TEST_DIR = tests

# Executables
MAIN_EXEC = library_management
TEST_EXEC = library_test

# Source files
MAIN_SRC = $(SRC_DIR)/main.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/Book.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/Library.cpp
TEST_SRC = $(TEST_DIR)/LibraryTest.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/Book.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/Library.cpp

# Build main program
$(MAIN_EXEC): $(MAIN_SRC)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(MAIN_EXEC) $(MAIN_SRC)

# Build test program
$(TEST_EXEC): $(TEST_SRC)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(TEST_EXEC) $(TEST_SRC)

I found a way to make each project with other command. but then I eed to run make and make test commands for making both of the projects.
# Default target: build only the main program
all: $(MAIN_EXEC)

# Build main program
$(MAIN_EXEC): $(MAIN_SRC)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(MAIN_EXEC) $(MAIN_SRC)

# Build test program
test: $(TEST_EXEC)

$(TEST_EXEC): $(TEST_SRC)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(TEST_EXEC) $(TEST_SRC)

Is there an option to make both of the projects in one make command?
Thanks!

all: $(MAIN_EXEC) $(TEST_EXEC)?

Simply type make all test.

As @some-programmer-dude commented, I added both of the projects to the all command and now it is making both of the projects:
all:$(MAIN_EXEC) $(TEST_EXEC)

My makefile looks now like this:
# Compiler and flags
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Iinclude

# Directories
SRC_DIR = src
INCLUDE_DIR = include
TEST_DIR = tests

# Executables
MAIN_EXEC = library_management
TEST_EXEC = library_test

# Source files
MAIN_SRC = $(SRC_DIR)/main.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/Book.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/Library.cpp
TEST_SRC = $(TEST_DIR)/LibraryTest.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/Book.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/Library.cpp

# Default target: build main and test programs
all:$(MAIN_EXEC) $(TEST_EXEC)

$(MAIN_EXEC): $(MAIN_SRC)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(MAIN_EXEC) $(MAIN_SRC)

$(TEST_EXEC): $(TEST_SRC)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(TEST_EXEC) $(TEST_SRC)

# Clean up
clean:
    rm -f $(MAIN_EXEC) $(TEST_EXEC)


main_exec and test_exec is undefined in your example. presumably it will be empty strings. your make all command will not work.

@user14063792468 I updated now the answer with all themake file commands, hope it will help others.

makefile comment say "build only the main command". should n t it be "build both targets"?

That makefile comment was misleading even for the original makefile.  Building all never affirmatively prevented building other targets as well, so the "only" qualifier was predicated on an unsafe assumption about how make would be used.  make all test is a viable, and fairly conventional option for use with the original makefile.
